# No output when merge function is called

Tags: c++, vector, stack

I have a doubt in the following code. Can somebody please explain.

```
  using namespace std;
    #define INT_SIZE 32
    #define R 4
    #define C 4
    #define N 4

    #include <iostream>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<math.h>
    #include<limits.h>
    #include<stack>
    #include<vector>
    #include<algorithm>


    struct interval{
        int start;
        int end;
    };

    bool compareInterval(interval i1, interval i2)
    {
        return (i1.start < i2.start)? true: false;
    }


    int merge(vector<interval>& a, int n)
    {
        stack<interval> s;
        sort(a.begin(), a.end(), compareInterval);
        s.push(a[0]);
        int i=1;
        interval temp;
        while(i<n)
        {
            temp = s.top();
            s.pop();
            if(temp.end > a[i].start && a[i].end > temp.end)
            {
                temp.end = a[i].end;
                s.push(temp);
            }
            else if(temp.end < a[i].start)
            {
                s.push(temp);
                s.push(a[i]);
            }
            i++;
        }
        while(s.size())
        {
            temp = s.top();
            cout << temp.start << "  ";
            cout << temp.end << "\n";
            s.pop();
        }
        return 0;
    }


    int main()
    {
     interval intvls[] = { {6,8}, {1,9}, {2,4}, {4,7} };
            vector<interval> intervals(intvls, intvls+4);

            for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
                {cout << intervals[i].start;
}   // This output is not coming when merge                      function is called


         cout <<  merge(intervals, 4);
    }
```

My doubt is "When I comment the merge function call i.e

```
//        cout <<  merge(intervals, 4);
```

When I comment this line, then I am able to see output of `cout<<intervals[i].start.`
Otherwise, I am not able to see the output.

"

Answer (score 0):

You are not ending your output with a newline. Try:

```
{cout << intervals[i].start << "\n";}
```

Without the newline, this output is probably getting hidden amongst all the output produced by `merge()`.

Answer (score 0):

There are few issues with this code.

```
 s.push(a[0]); <-- Only on element is in you stack.
 //s.push(a[1]).. you will have to add all other elements like this.

 while(i<n)
 {
    temp = s.top(); <-- for second i s will be empty. Here you must check if stack is empty before getting top element.
    s.pop();
 }
```

Your first output is not printed correctly. use `std::endl`

```
cout << intervals[i].start << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in `merge` that leads to a segmentation fault. Due to this `std::cout` is not flushed. If you comment out the line with the merge call, `std::cout` is flushed when the program exits.